# difficulty figuring out what is wrong in my code

Tags: python

I'm getting an error back when I try and run a piece of code and I'm not sure why. My error message is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\srv-005\student2011documents$\hbyrne11\My Documents\GCSE Computing\controlled assesment(Python)\controlled assessment VM\CA Harry.py", line 130, in <module>
    print (cl)
NameError: name 'cl' is not defined"
```

My code looks like:

```
Score = 10
Class = Class + ".txt"
file = open(Class,'a')
Name = (name)
file.write(str(Name + ":")) 
file.write(str(Score))
file.write("\n")
file.close()



if Class == "1":
    with open("1.txt", 'r') as file:
        cl = {}
        for record in file:
            n, s = record.split(':')
            try:
                cl[n].append(int(s))
            except KeyError:
                cl[n] = [int(s),]
    file.close()

if Class == "2":
    with open("2.txt", 'r') as file:
        cl = {}
        for record in file:
            n, s = record.split(':')
            try:
                cl[n].append(int(s))
            except KeyError:
                cl[n] = [int(s),]
    file.close()


if Class == "3":
    with open("3.txt", 'r') as file:
        cl = {}
        for record in file:
            n, s = record.split(':')
            try:
                cl[n].append(int(s))
            except KeyError:
                cl[n] = [int(s),]
    file.close()

print ("-------------------------")
print ("Class"+" "+Class + "'s "+"results")
print (cl) 
print ("-------------------------")
alphabetically = sorted(cl.items(), key = lambda t: t[0])
print ("Sorted Alphabetically:")
print(" /// ".join(["{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in alphabetically]))  
print ("-------------------------")
print ("Sorted Highest to Lowest:")
valuesort = sorted(cl.items(), key=(lambda t:max(t[1])), reverse=True)
print(" /// ".join(["{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in valuesort]))  
print ("-------------------------")
print ("Average by Highest to Lowest:")
averagesort = sorted([(k,sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in cl.items()], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(" /// ".join(["{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in averagesort]))  
print ("-------------------------")
```

Comment: Me too. Please explain what your code is supposed to do. And give us more information on what your troubleshooting lead you to believe the problem is. Help us help you.

Comment: @idjaw my code is a maths quiz that is supposed to sort students into classes 1,2,3 depending on what they entered. then sort their results alphabetically,by average and by highest score. ive got the quiz and the points but im having difficulty sorting them into the three pervious categories, which is what this code is attempting! hope thats enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I didn't catch what the other two answers said about how you've changed Class so that it will never equal 1, 2, 3.

changing your if clauses to

```
if Class == "1.txt":
    #code
elif Class == "2.txt":
    #code
elif Class == "3.txt":
    #code
else:
    #code to deal with Class not being what you think it should be.
    # perhaps something like
    raise RuntimeError("Class is {}.\n".format(Class))
```

should fix the problem. I think you should change the second and third if statements to elif. There's no point in having the interpreter check all three when only one of them will apply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `Class` variable will end with "`.txt`" according to the second line of code you posted, so none of the three cases will apply and the variable `cl` will never be assigned. That's why it cannot be found in the scope when trying to print it, and a `NameError` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting says, there's no variable with the name `cl` defined. I think this is because you want to define `cl` in those `if` statements, but you override your variable `Class` with **something.txt** so `Class` is never  one of **"1"**, **"2"** or **"3"** and the `if` statement is never reached.

Hope this helps!